# Why won't my netbook read by USB drive?

Tags: installation, boot, usb, live-usb, bios

I have a problem installing Ubuntu via USB storage using unetbootin:
My notebook BIOS does not read the USB key, instead of another notebook that I tried that does.

I think the problem is that USB ports are not active because if I go in BIOS settings in the page in which I can set what device is ran first, the bios does not show me the name of the USB drive, instead of the other notebook that does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for something called USB Legacy Support in the BIOS or similar. Enabling that should allow the machine to pretend the USB key is a hard drive and boot from it. Ubuntu should take over from there.

Comment: Right answer!! Thank you and thank everybody tried to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Are you shure, that your BIOS supports booting from USB?

If your BIOS does not list USB, make shure you pluged in your device BEFORE starting your laptop.

Do you have UEFI? Maybe this is your problem.

Maybe [this site](https://superuser.com/questions/507111/if-usb-is-not-listed-in-bios-as-a-boot-option-does-that-mean-the-machine-cant) will help you.

EDIT:

Maybe you have to activate your USB device in the BIOS, search for "Inegrated Peripherals"

Comment: i am quite sure that does support it because there are listed 3 usb options, like in my other notebook, such as the one that is used that is called usb hdd ..

Comment: i can't find anything like integrated peripherals :/

Comment: if i go in boot section, i can see some choices:

Comment: the first one is called boot device priority, i go there, there is the list of the devices launched in order of priority, but usb hdd does not have nothing written on the right, instead of the hard disk and the dvd reader that have respective names on the right..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that computer doesn't like the way your software boots [I've had that problem before] there's a lot of good software for booting Linux from USB at [pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) [all free!]